# Play 2.0! [Java] - Generating XML response from the REST API

Tags: rest, playframework-2.0

I am parsing through Play framework documents and trying to figure out if there is anything out of the box available for generating XML response from the given domain object, just like how we have for `Json.toJson(Object)`.

The following code works fine for Json REST API in play framework 2.1.2, can anyone suggest how can XML be generated out of the box here instead of Json?

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import play.Logger;
import play.libs.F.Function;
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.model.Item;

public class ShowItemsJson extends Controller {

    public static Result allItems() {
        // Now create the async process to lookup items in simpledb
        AllItems<List<Item>> callable = new AllItems<List<Item>>();
        Promise<List<Item>> promise = play.libs.Akka.future(callable);
        return async(promise.map(new Function<List<Item>, Result>() {
            public Result apply(List<Item> rm) throws Throwable {
                // Convert the result into json before sending.
                // TODO How to do same for XML?
                return ok(Json.toJson(rm));
            }
        }));
    }

    // One instance of this class should be used for each create request
    static class AllItems<V> implements Callable<V> {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public V call() throws Exception {
            try {
                return (V) Test.getAllItems();
            } catch (Error e) {
                // Error is handled here to log NoClassDefFoundError
                Logger.error("Error: ", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `json to XML converter` -  http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/279-how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-java/ OR http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.UgHgDpKnr08 OR http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/XML.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for generating XML from Java objects in Play 2 as far as I know, there are loads of options in Java-land though.

To name a few:

- JAXB for doing it with reflection/annotations - reference implementation http://jaxb.java.net
- xom - http://www.xom.nu
- jdom - http://www.jdom.org,
- dom4j - http://dom4j.sourceforge.net